# Splitting one file into multiple files

Tags: perl, bash, shell, sed

I have a large file like below, I want to split this file into multiple files. Each file should be break after ENDMDL. For the following file there will be three output files with name pose1.av, pose2.av and pose3.av.

```
MODEL        1
SML    170  O   PRO A  17      16.893   3.030   0.799  1.00  1.00           O
SML    171  OXT PRO A  17      18.167   2.722   2.597  1.00  1.00           O
TER     172      PRO A  17
ENDMDL
MODEL        2
SML      4  CG  ARG A   1      -2.171  -7.105  -4.278  1.00  1.00           C
SML      5  CD  ARG A   1      -1.851  -8.581  -4.022  1.00  1.00           C
SML    113  HD1 HIS A  12       2.465  -8.206   5.062  1.00  1.00           H
TER     114      HIS A  12
ENDMDL
MODEL        3
SML    101  N   HIS A  12       3.765  -3.995   7.233  1.00  1.00           N
SML    102  CA  HIS A  12       2.584  -4.736   6.934  1.00  1.00           C
TER     103      HIS A  12
ENDMDL
```

Answer (score 4):

A rather efficient one, using bash and sed:

```
n=0
while IFS= read -r firstline; do
    { echo "$firstline"; sed '/^ENDMDL$/q'; } > "pose$((++n)).av"
done < file
```

It's much more efficient than the other Bash answer: the output file is only opened once, and most of the parsing is done by sed, and not by bash.

Comment: Nice! I understand how each of these commands work, but how is `sed` receiving any input?

Comment: @JoshJolly it just read from stdin! the `read` reads one line from stdin and the sed until the `ENDMDL` and so on... the file `file` is fed to stdin of the whole `while` block.

Answer (score 4):

[csplit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csplit) can do this out of the box

```
csplit -z -s -f pose -b "%01d.av" file '/^ENDMDL$/+1' '{*}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Awk is a good choice for this task:

```
awk '{file="pose"++i;printf "%s%s",$0,RS > file;close(file)}' RS='ENDMDL\n' file
```

Comment: This needs to be a `gnu awk` due to multiple characters in Record Selector.

Answer (score 3):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -ne '$fh or open $fh, "> pose".++$i".av"; print $fh $_; undef $fh if /^ENDMDL/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

In pure Bash:

```
cnt=1
while read line; do
    echo "$line" >> pose${cnt}.av
    [ "$line" == "ENDMDL" ] && let cnt+=1
done < filename.txt
```

Comment: Use either `[ ... = ... ]` (POSIX) or `[[ ... == ... ]]`, `[ ... == ... ]` is not standards-conformant and some shells will choke on it.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/^MODEL/{out="pose"++cnt".av"} {print > out}' file
```